# How to dynamically render content based on object property and path in url

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, javascript-objects

I have an object array like this:

```
const products = [
{
name: 'prod1',
category: 'cat1',
pageID: 'product-001',
},{
name: 'prod1',
category: 'cat1',
pageID: 'product-001',
},{
name: 'prod1',
category: 'cat1',
pageID: 'product-001',
}];
```

And I'm rendering those as a product list on in my app. Every position on the rendered product list should link to specific product view. So far I came up with the `pageID` property, that is passed to link as props. Works fine - paths are correct.

Problem I have:
When trying to render a specific product view, I'm mapping my object array. How do I check if my `window.location.pathname` is the same as one of the object's `pageID`, and then get the name and category of only this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `reduce` that array into an object with the keys being the `pageID` and the values being an object of `name, category`:

```js
const products = [{
  name: 'prod1',
  category: 'cat1',
  pageID: 'product-001'
}, {
  name: 'prod2',
  category: 'cat2',
  pageID: 'product-002'
}, {
  name: 'prod2',
  category: 'cat2',
  pageID: 'product-002'
}];

const pageIDs = products.reduce((a, { name, category, pageID }) => ({ ...a, [pageID]: { name, category }}), {});

let windowPathname = "product-002";

console.log(pageIDs[windowPathname]);
```

<sub>(I edited your sample data to show that it works)</sub>